# jupyter replacing column values with other DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, jupyter

I have a DataFrame (DF1) with a matching pairs "code - description" (2 columns: one for "code", second for "description). Second DataFrame (DF2) contain a list of "codes" in a column.
I want to replace those "codes" in the second DataFrame (DF2) with the "descriptions" from DF1 where DF1"code" will match DF2"code".
DF1 have contain only a portion of "codes" stored in DF1
thank you
[DataFrames graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDtUg.png)

DF1

aaa1 ----- first_letter_one

aaa2 ----- first_letter_two

aaa3 ----- first_letter_three

bbb1 ----- second_letter_one

bbb2 ----- second_letter_two

bbb3 ----- second_letter_three

ccc1 ----- third_letter_one

ccc2 ----- third_letter_two

ccc3 ----- third_letter_three

DF2

aaa1

bbb2

bbb3

ccc2

DF2 after

first_letter_one

second_letter_two

second_letter_three

third_letter_two

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a left join on df2, if df1 is large dataset, use **join with set_index** instead of merge,

```
df1.set_index('code', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('code', inplace=True)
df_joined = df2.join(df1, how='left')
```

Then select only the description column

```
df_joined["description"]
```

Comment: because DF1 was larger, in my case I had to use inner joint, thank you

Comment: @Yggrson Could you tell me the shape of DF1 ?

Comment: """"""""""search_names = pd.merge(DF2.iloc[0], DF1, on='Indicator Code', how='inner')""""""""" 
""""""""new_names = search_names['Indicator Name'] """""""""""  where 'Indicator Code' was a column that had common data eg the "code". thank you again for the help :)